# Augment Restify request object via a Typescript declaration file

Tags: javascript, typescript, restify

I'm trying to add a property to the `restify.Request` object which in JavaScript is pretty simple: `restify.Request.newProperty = true` but it is not as straight forward using Typescript.
I imagine the best way would be to augment the Restify declaration file. It looks like this:

```
export interface Request {
     ...
}
```

So I've created a directory to store my local declaration files , defined it... and created a file `restify.d.ts` which contains:

```
import * as restify from "restify";

declare module "restify" {
    interface Request {
        newProperty?: boolean;
    }
}
```

This seems to work to some extent, I do have visibility of `newProperty` but I lost visibility of everything that originally came with `restify`, so it looks like I'm just overwriting instead of extending/augmenting.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try renaming `restify.d.ts` to `restify.augment.d.ts` or anything else. From my testing the name of this file masks the original module

Comment: I just gave your example a try, and it seems to be working as expected - I can reference your added property on the `Request` interface, `newProperty`, but I can still access existing properties (like `authorization` or `log`).